# Why are the buttons not working when i run the app?

Tags: java, android-studio

My app doesn't response when i type 
 Android app project that has two (2) text fields and one (1) button. The button will
compare the input from the text fields and display a response (SAME if values are the same
and NOT THE SAME if they are not) if it is clicked. You may need to create a new activity
for this.

```
package com.demesaict203.fieldchecker;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button checkbtn =  (Button)findViewById(R.id.checkBtn);
    checkbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            EditText firstttextEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firsttextEditText);
            EditText secondtextEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.secondtextEditText);

            if (firstttextEditText.equals(secondtextEditText)){
                Intent sameTextIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SameText.class);
                startActivity(sameTextIntent);
            }
            else{
                Intent notsameTextIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NotTheSame.class);
                startActivity(notsameTextIntent);
            }

        }
    });
  }
 }
```

Here is my **XML** code:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:id="@+id/checkButton"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     tools:context=".MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/firsttextEditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/enter_word"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:autofillHints="" tools:targetApi="o" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/secondtextEditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/enter_word"
    android:importantForAutofill="no"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/firsttextEditText" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/checkBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/check"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/secondtextEditText" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, you can't compare two `EditText` references together to get the result of text values equality.

you can get the text wrote in the editText using `getText()` method

then start to compare both strings values.

also, I suggest declaring `EditText` out of scope `setOnClickListener` so that not declare new instances every time the user click button.

so your final java code can be like :

```
package com.demesaict203.fieldchecker;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        EditText firstttextEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firsttextEditText);
        EditText secondtextEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.secondtextEditText);
        Button checkbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.checkBtn);
        checkbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String firstValue = firstttextEditText.getText().toString();
                String secondValue = secondtextEditText.getText().toString();
                if (firstValue.equals(secondValue)) {
                    Intent sameTextIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SameText.class);
                    startActivity(sameTextIntent);
                } else {
                    Intent notsameTextIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotTheSame.class);
                    startActivity(notsameTextIntent);
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

I suggest you learn more about `EditText` from [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText)

Comment: the IDE ask me to set to final the EditText

Comment: it's ok you can do it final or make it declared outside of `onCreate` scope

what u mean by not responding?

Comment: there are two edit text in my app i type "gg" in the first blank then "gg" in the second and press check button. from there the app should go to the same text view but it didn't

Comment: it didn't do anything? have you tried to `debug` click listener? or print log values?

Comment: The whole program was ok sir thanks to you. I realized that the problem was on the emulator because i run that on  bluestacks. Luckly I have chance to run my program on my schools laboratory and it runs properly.

Answer (score 0):

you are comparing the EditText, not the text inside the edit text. maybe change your codes to something like this.

```
String firstttextEditText = findViewById(R.id.firsttextEditText)).getText().toString();
String secondtextEditText = findViewById(R.id.secondtextEditText).getText().toString();

if (firstttextEditText.equals(secondtextEditText)){
    Intent sameTextIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SameText.class);
    startActivity(sameTextIntent);
}
else{
    Intent notsameTextIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NotTheSame.class);
    startActivity(notsameTextIntent);
}
```